# Out of memory issue using picassa with RecylerView

Tags: android

I am displaying list of images in `Recyerview` using `picassa` in multiple `Tabs`. I facing `out of memory` issue. Please sugguest solution.

Regards
Sanjeev Badoni

Comment: please provide some code of what you are trying.

Comment: tho only solution is not to show images in tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Try stop caching on Picasso:

Picasso.with(getContext()).load(data.get(pos).getFeed_thumb_image()).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(image);